# Loglikelihood of logit minor help

Tags: logistic, likelihood

I'm trying to derive the loglikelihood of the logit model, and I already found material that covers this, but I'm not sure in some steps how they did it. I am attaching the solution of it, and if someone could clarify for me the third and fourth equations from the end I would be thankful. Why is it multiplied by $exp(x_i\beta)$ and why then it is transformed into ln$\frac{1}{1+exp(x_i\beta)}$. For reference [this is where I found it](https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-statistics/logistic-model-maximum-likelihood)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just arithmetic on powers. Multiplying by something equal to 1 is a common trick for simplifying fractions.

$$
\frac{e^{-a}}{1 + e^{-a}} = \frac{e^{-a}}{1 + e^{-a}}\frac{e^a}{e^a} = \frac{e^{-a}e^a}{e^a + e^{-a}e^a} = \frac{1}{e^a + 1}
$$

The reason "why" is to make it simpler. In the last form there is only $x_{i}\beta$ on the bottom, not on both the top and bottom.

Comment: :) thank you for clarifying it to me. Sometimes it really is just that simple and I'm suddenly blind